# Fstream doesnt save the last word in the file and it doesnt read from the file, too

Tags: c++, string, iostream, fstream

This a simple code for registering games in a file, but there are two problems.

First, the parameter or attribute "clasification" is not being saved in the file.

And second, when I read from the file, the content isn't shown.

Before commenting, you have to know that this is my first time working with files and I'm trying to learn on my own.

And I know this code lacks of modularity and I should declare a vector of pointers of objects, not to objects,  or I should smart pointers, but I just wanted to show you the problem that I have with the file.

Any help is really appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;
using std::fstream;

struct Games
{
 string name;
 string gender;
 string clasification;
 int year;
};

struct VectorGames
{
 vector<Games>VectorForGames;
 void InsertGame(string n, string g, string c, int y)
 {
    Games New = Games();
    New.name = n;
    New.gender = g;
    New.clasification = c;
    New.year = y;
    VectorForGames.push_back(New);
 }
};

int main()
{
 string name;
 string gender;
 string clasification;
 int year = 0;
 int option = 0;
 VectorGames V;
 fstream File("SavedGames.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app |     fstream::ate);
 do
 {
    cout << "1. Register a game " << endl
        << "2. Show the list of games registered" << endl
        << "3. Exit " << endl;
    cout << "Type in your option: ";
    cin >> option;
    cin.get();

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        cout << "Type in the name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Type in the gender: ";
        getline(cin, gender);
        cout << "Type in the clasification: ";
        getline(cin, gender);
        cout << "Type in the year: ";
        cin >> year;
        V.InsertGame(name, gender, clasification, year);
        if (File.is_open())
            File << "Name: " << name << "  Gender: " << gender
            << " Clasification: " << clasification << " Year: " << year << endl;
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        string temporal;
        while (getline(File, temporal))
        {
            cout << temporal << endl;
        }
        break;
    }

    case 3: File.close();
        break;

    default: cout << "Try again" << endl;

    }

} while (option != 3);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Could you possible take a look at? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also I would recommend learning how file streams work prior to incorperating it into an application. Try and write a program that just reads a single number from a file and prints it to the user. There is a ton of stuff that needs fixing, but you should probably learn about various elements prior to actually adding in more features.

Comment: Thanks  for commenting in my post.

Comment: Can you pls tell me what I should fix, what's wrong with my code besides what I described above?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind would be remove those using statements. In general it is a bad practice as it adds ambiguity. Its only 5 more characters to type std::string and once your project gets large, you will thank yourself for it. For the VectorGames struct, you could probably just have a vector of games, and then have a constructor/use c-style initialization for Games. Also use one file stream for input, one for output. (Otherwise you are bound to have defined but unwanted behaviour)

Comment: I'm gonna use one file for input and one the output. I think it's gonna solve the problem that I have with reading data from the file. Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    cout << "Type in the gender: ";
    getline(cin, gender);
    cout << "Type in the clasification: ";
    getline(cin, gender);
```

The problem is not with saving the entered "classification" in a file. The problem is that you read it into the wrong variable.

Comment: But, I can't still read the content from the file. Do you know why?

Comment: Read the file by creating a separate std::ifstream object, and reading it, instead of trying to recycle the object you're using for writing to the file.